# Navigate from Android ViewPager2 child fragment to another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-viewpager2

Is there a way to navigate from a child fragment of ViewPager2 to another fragment?
Let's say I have a parent fragment [ParentFragment] containing only a ViewPager2 and a TabLayout. I have 2 children fragments [ChildrenFragment1 and ChildrenFragment2] created with FragmentStateAdapter. I want to navigate from ChildrenFragment2 to another FragmentB so that when i navigate back from FragmentB, to show position of the ParentFragment to ChildFragment2?

ex: ChildFragment1 -> ChildFragment2 -> FragmentB -> ChildFragment2

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination id:actionChildFragment2_to_FragmentB cannot be found from the current destination
```

Comment: I think the action should be from parent `Fragment` to `FragmentB`.

Comment: Yes but how can i save the state that the navigation was made from ChildFragment2 to FragmentB?

Comment: I believe the state is auto-saved.

Comment: i have tried, it is not.

Comment: What did you get? What state you are trying to save?

Comment: As i wrote in the description, I have 2 child fragments: ChildFragment1 and ChildFragment2. If i navigate from ChildFragment2 to FragmentB, and when i press back, i want to show ChildFragment2, not to recreate the viewpager2 and start from the first fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, i keep the current page in a ViewModel LiveData property, setting it on page change inside the ParentFragment:

```
binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(page: Int) {
            viewModel.updatePageSelected(page)
        }
    })
```

and observe the page change inside the ParentFragment:

```
subscribeToLiveData(viewModel.viewPagerSelected) { page ->
        binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(page, false)
    }
```

The ParentViewModel:

```
private val _viewPagerSelected = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val viewPagerSelected: LiveData<Int> = _viewPagerSelected

fun updatePageSelected(newSelection: Int) {
    _viewPagerSelected.value = newSelection
}
```